# Cue-Me iOS Keyboard Autofocus

Tags: ios

I am making a hybrid app using Cue-Me. I've encountered a problem - autofocus will not bring up the keyboard on iOS. By design, iOS always requires a user touch before the keyboard will display.

In order to change this, I need to change the value of an iOS bool called "keyboarddisplayrequiresuseraction" from TRUE to FALSE. This is apparently a trivial task in other frameworks like Cordova, but there is not much documentation for Cue-Me online, so I am unsure how to approach the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, a friend showed me a work-around called "Method Swizzling." This solution worked, and autofocus properly brings up the keyboard in iOS now!

More info here - http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/